# Is it possible to isolate browsing data to a specific SSAS partition

Tags: multidimensional-array, ssas, analysisservices

Is it possible to check which partition data resides in on a multidimensional Analysis Services cube?

I'd like to make sure that data is contained in a particular partition, but I'm not sure how I could query for this.

Comment: I saw a failure when migrating data to a historical partition. I would like to know whether the processing of the partition completed or was rolled back. That got me wondering if it is possible to interrogate individual partitions to see what data resides within them.